# How to search index in all columns of multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, search, multidimensional-array

I am trying to get the index of multidimensional array in all columns of nested arrays. Example:

```
 $array = 
 [ 
      "int" => [80,85,66],
      "text" => [57,58],
      "varchar" => [82,72,70],
      "decimal" => [60,61]
 ];
```

I want to search a function in php (combinated) to get the tpye from Id like this:

with 61 return "deicmal" (index) 
with 58 return "text"

But only combined with array **php core functions, without for loops**

Comment: loop and in_array ?

Comment: Depending on how many times you need to do this for the same dataset, I would first loop through this array and create a new array which maps the numbers onto the string. Then it would be a simple case of accessing that array by the search index to find the result.

Comment: check array_filter function

Comment: This question is unclear about whether it only needs to return a single key or potentially return multiple qualifying rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you want, but you can check this solution:

```
<?php

$array =
[
    "int" => [80,85,66],
    "text" => [57,58],
    "varchar" => [82,72,70],
    "decimal" => [60,61]
];

getTypeFromId(61, $array);

function getTypeFromId($index, $array) {
    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
        if (in_array($index, $v)) {
            echo "With " . $index . " return " . $k;
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
With 61 return decimal
```

Comment: I want a function like ```getTypeFromId($id, $array) { array_search($id, array_seacrch(...))}``` somthing like that...

Comment: thanks but I need only with php fucntions without foreach, is it possible with array_search and any combination?

Comment: It is possible if you have one array, but you have nested arrays.

Comment: ok thanks! if is not possible is the answer of my question :)

Answer (score 2):

With reference to comment from php documentation [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php#91365).

```
$array = 
[ 
      "int" => [80,85,66],
      "text" => [57,58],
      "varchar" => [82,72,70],
      "decimal" => [60,61]
];
function recursive_array_search($needle,$haystack) {
    foreach($haystack as $key=>$value) {
        $current_key=$key;
        if($needle===$value OR (is_array($value) && recursive_array_search($needle,$value) !== false)) {
            return $current_key;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

echo recursive_array_search(61,$array); // decimal
echo recursive_array_search(58,$array); // text
```

Comment: He doesn't want `foreach` only php core functions.

Comment: array_search in recursive way, OP can use my recursive array search function as a core function and reuse it.

Comment: Dude .. he doesn't want to iterate over array

Comment: There is nothing as such, unto my knowledge.

Comment: Well, thank you for your answer, the question was I want to know if its possible to get the answer through array_search or combination with array search and other array functions from php with one line, but it seems not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Here we filter the original array to contain only the arrays that contain the wanted number.  We then just get the key of that one remaining element.  (Assuming all your numbers are unique.)

```
<?php

$array = 
[ 
    "int" => [80,85,66],
    "text" => [57,58],
    "varchar" => [82,72,70],
    "decimal" => [60,61]
];

$target = 70;
$filtered = array_filter($array, function($v) use ($target) {
    return in_array($target, $v);
});

echo key($filtered);
```

Output:

```
varchar
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't averse to foreach, you can just traverse your array, and each sub-array until you match your item.

```
<?php
$array = 
[ 
    "int"     => [80,85,66],
    "text"    => [57,58],
    "varchar" => [82,72,70],
    "decimal" => [60,61]
];

function find_type($needle, $array)
{
    foreach($array as $type => $sub)
        foreach($sub as $int)
            if($int == $needle) return $type;
}

echo find_type(60, $array);
```

Output:

```
 decimal
```